# Discrete Event Modeling: designing reverse flows and loops in AnyLogic 7

Tags: simulation, modeling, anylogic

I am looking at the discrete event simulation model demo on AnyLogic 7 that has customers coming in to ATM and Bank tellers and trying to understand how to model the following:

1. If a customer, after visiting ATM, decides to join the bank teller queue
2. If a customer, after visiting ATM, decides to join the ATM queue (to withdraw more money)

I explored the properties view and looked at writing java code but this approach doesn't seem to help. Appreciate any help/guidance provided on how to implement such flows.

Sincerely,

Comment: When you say discrete event simulation, do you mean that you are trying to use Agents and collections, or are you trying to use the Process library / palette items? Some people mean different things when they say "discrete event." :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about this model:
[image: Anylogic Bank model]
This model already models your first request. The "magic" is done in the `NeedAdditionalService` element where 30% (the specified value is 0.3) of all customers that are done at the ATM are sent to the cashiers, because they need additional service. You find that property if you click on that element in the properties tab/window.

For the second request you could add another `Select Output` element behind the `NeedAdditionalService` element to send one fraction of the customers to the `tmend` element and the other fraction back to the ATM queue. Your model would look like this then:
[image: Edited Anylogic Bank model]

Comment: My sincere apologies for not responding earlier -- was reading this from my mobile device. Yes, your post helped. Many thanks!